# Is it a good practice to call setState method while using Bloc architecture in Flutter?

Tags: entity-framework, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I'm using bloc architecture for my project, and I'm trying to disable/enable the form based upon the checkbox value.

Here is my code->>>

```
Widget _buildSameAsResidential(BuildContext context) {
return StreamBuilder<FormValue<bool, String>>(
  initialData: _addressBloc.residentailEqualMailingValue,
  stream: _addressBloc.residentailEqualMailing,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    return MemberFormField(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[

          Checkbox(
            onChanged: (isChecked) {
              setState(() {
                _isBothAddressEquals = isChecked;
              });
              _addressBloc.dispatch(
                  UpdateResidentialEqualMailing(value: isChecked));
            },
            value: snapshot.data.value,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no crime in using setState together with bloc if the need arises, but for the way use are using it in your code, setState is not needed. The checkbox state has been handled by the block.

Comment: Need of setState method arises because i want to update _isBothAddressEquals variable, and when i'm updating this variable using " _isBothAddressEquals = snapshot.data.value"  it is not updating the widgets based upon the value of _isBothAddressEquals, i.e the reason i'm using setState here

Answer (score 0):

Mixing two different state managements is not good. Although I didn't see any errors while mixing them (and we have assurance that `BLoC` is not removing calls to `setState`), still it does not look good regarding clean architecture.

So there is a rule:  **Avoid `setState` wherever you can**.

Of course sometimes it is not possible (for example for animations) and then you should use `setSate`.

According to your case...

You should:

1. create `BLoC Event` - `BothAddressEqualsCheck` with `isChecked` property.
2. add `bothAddressEqualsCheck` (`bool`) property to `BLoC State`.
3. Wrap your `Checkbox` with `BlocBuilder`
4. In `Checkbox value` use `state.bothAddressEqualsCheck`.
5. In `Checkbox onChanged` call the `BothAddressEqualsCheck` event and pass the `isChecked` as parameter.